# Google Chart MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-visualization

I am using Json to return the data in my Controller and in my View, I am trying to get the Json data and using Google chart API, i am trying to display it, but am getting nothing.  But I am getting the data, if i called the data actionresult alone.

In my Controller [Home]:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class PieChart
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal valor { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<PieChart> CreateDataList()
    {
        var data = new List<PieChart>()
        {
            new PieChart() {Name = "Introduction", valor = 20},
            new PieChart() {Name = "InBasic 1", valor = 60},
            new PieChart() {Name = "PHP", valor = 80}
        };

        return data;
    }

    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        return Json(CreateDataList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Chart()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in my View [Chart.cshtml]:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

function drawVisualization() {
    $.get('GetData', {}, function(data) {
        var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        tdata.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        tdata.addColumn('number', 'Hours');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tdata.addRow([data[i].Name, data[i].valor]);
        }

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(tdata, { title: "Top Videos", pieHole: 0.4 });


    });
};

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

But, my view renders nothing.

Any pointers ?

Comment: Are you hitting the controller method? You should be using `$.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function(data) { ...` to ensure you url is correctly generated. What if any errors do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke, Yes I am getting a console, "Uncaught TypeError: google.setOnLoadCallback is not a function"

Comment: after replacing with $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function(data) { ..., I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PieChart' of undefined"

Comment: Sounds like your scripts are not loading correctly (or may be in the wrong order)

Comment: I made a mistake of creating a .cshtml for GetData() as well, and when I removed the GetData.cshtml, now i am able to render the chart